# How to fetch values from Nested foreach loop array (fetch Product details category-wise)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long array from which I wish to fetch all the values to show
 them php front-end page. I have two tables in database.

1. Category - cat_id, cat_name;
2. List item product - pro_id, cat_id,
   cat_name,  pro_name, price;

   My array is given below:

   ```
   Array( [0] => Array (
               [3] => Array( [cat_id] => 3
                       [cat_name] => Mobile Phones
                       [product] => Array(
                               [26] => Array(
                                       [pro_id] => 26
                                       [pro_name] => iPhone 7
                                       [price] => 70000
                                   )
                               [25] => Array(
                                       [id] => 25
                                       [pro_name] => iPhone 6
                                       [price] => 60000
                                   )                           
                           )
                   )
           )

       [1] => Array(
               [5] => Array([id] => 5
                       [name] => Software
                       [product] => Array(
                               [21] => Array(
                                       [id] => 21
                                       [pro_name] => Lorem Ipsum is simply
                                       [price] => 5000
                                   )
                               [11] => Array
                                   (
                                       [id] => 11
                                       [pro_name] => Lorem Ipsum is simply
                                       [price] => 10000
                                   )
                           )
                   )
           )
   [2] => Array( [4] => Array([id] => 4
                       [name] => Accessories
                       [product] => Array(
                               [20] => Array(
                                       [id] => 20
                                       [pro_name] => japan
                                       [price] => 40000
                                   )
                           )
                   )
           )
   ```

I am unable to fetch the values of this array by using this code:

```
if(!empty($product)){
            foreach($product as $catname){
              echo $catname['cat_name'];
              echo "<br>";
               foreach($product[] as $detail=> $row {
                    echo $row['product_id'];
                    echo $row['pro_name'];
                    echo $row['price'];         
               }
```

Its showing error. But I want output like this:

```
Mobile Phones
   26
   iPhone 7
   70000

   25
   iPhone 6
   60000


Software
   21
   Lorem Ipsum is simply
   5000

   11
   Lorem Ipsum is simply
   10000


Accessories
   20
   japan
   40000
```

Comment: Will you put it in an array values instead of array output? It's hard to trace when indention is not so clear

Comment: I don't get why there are some `cat_id` or `pro_id` instead of `id` in your array.

Comment: sorry its mistakenly typed...now corrected

Answer (score 0):

easy, only can use this function:

```
function array_echo($array , $indent = 0)
{

    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        echo "<br />";
        for($i=0; $i<$indent; $i++) 
             echo "&emsp;&emsp;";
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            echo "[$k] => ";
            array_echo($v, ($indent+1));
        }
        else
            echo "[$k] => [$v]";
    }
}
```